# Given a set of points in space, determine that point from the set that is the closest to another point in space (that's not in the set)

Tags: java, algorithm, math, graphics

I've been asked recently to implement two classes that represent `Point2D` points and `Point3D` points. The distance and the other methods work fine, yet there's only one left that needs to be implemented and I can't figure out the algorithm. It's stated like this:

**"Given a set of points in space, determine that point from the set that is the closest to another point in space (that's not in the set)"**

Below are the two classes. Can anybody help me with the last needed algorithm?

```
    public class Point2D {
    protected double x;
    protected double y;

    public Point2D() { }

    public Point2D(double x, double y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double getX() { return x; }
    public void setX(double x) { this.x = x; }
    public double getY() { return y; }
    public void setY(double y) { this.y = y; }

    public double Point2DDistance(Point2D punct)
    {
        double px = this.x - punct.x;
        double py = this.y - punct.y;

        return Math.sqrt((px * px) + (py * py));
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "(" + x + ", " + y + ")";
    } 
}

public class Point3D extends Point2D {
    private double z;

    public Point3D() { }

    public Point3D(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        super(x, y);
        this.z = z;
    }

    public double getZ() { return z; }
    public void setZ(double z) { this.z = z; }

    public double Point3DDistance(Point3D punct)
    {
        double pz = this.z - punct.z;

        return this.Point2DDistance(punct) + Math.sqrt(pz * pz);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "(" + this.x + ", " + this.y + ", " + this.z + ")";
    }
}
```

Comment: it's just a problem of finding the min. Iterate through out the points, calculate the distance between them and the target point and always save the point corresponding to the min distance together with the min distance.

Comment: Check your equation for distance in 3-dimensional space.

Comment: @A.Webb is there something wrong with it?

Comment: @Kyprulez `sqrt(x^2 + y^2) + sqrt(z^2) <> sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate through the points.

For each point,

- if this is the first point, set `min_distance` = the point's distance to the not-in-set point *P*, and copy this point to `closestP`, and
- otherwise, if this point's distance to *P* is less than `min_distance`, set `min_distance` to this point's distance, and copy this point to `closestP`.

Now `closestP` holds the closest point, and `min_distance` holds the distance it has from *P*.

Hurray!